# Recommended way of packaging a boost::python module?

Tags: python, packaging, c++

I have a one-file boost::python module which is compiled using a one-line Makefile. What is the recommended way of packaging it? Distutils? Makefile? CMake? Use CDBS then? Are there some documents on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally used `distutils` (very short `setup.py`) then run `dh_make` which sets up debhelper-based (almost empty) `debian/rules` and most of the rest. Result is [here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~eudoxos/minieigen/trunk/files/head:/).

Comment: I use distutils.  The only issue some people have with it is that it doesn't usually 'fit' neatly with aptitude and doesn't offer an uninstall option